# Perl regex: how to replace terminal control characters with html tags?

Tags: html, regex, perl

How do I replace terminal control characters with HTML tags ?

```
my ($black,$red,$green,$reset) = ('^[[30m','^[[38m','^[[92m','^[[0m');    

my $LogString = $red.'red'.$reset;

printf ("%s\n",$LogString);

$LogString =~s/$red/<font color="red">/g;
$LogString =~s/$reset/<\/font>/g;

printf HTML ("%s\n",$LogString);
```

Comment: Consider using CSS and not `font` tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you properly escape the characters in your regex. Otherwise, the regex *metacharacters* such as `[` in `^[[38m` (`$red`) for example is thought to be the opening delimiter of a character class.

Consider changing to this:

```
$LogString =~s/\Q$red\E/<font color="red">/g;
$LogString =~s/\Q$reset\E/<\/font>/g;
```

The `\Q` and `\E` disable and reenable the regex metacharacters respectively.

See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for more details.